# RF External matching network - mixer IC

Tags: rf, radio, mixer

I have question about mixer IC (Max2335),

datasheet:
https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2335.pdf

LNAOUT and MIXIN in pin description (p. 5) have notice: 
"Requires an external matching network".
As I understand these external components (like on schematic - p. 9) are part of 50 Ohm matching impedance with LNA output and separately MIXIN input?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: I don't see that "notice" on pg 5 as you stated. Can you be clear about what you are saying? Please also be clear about what your question is.

Comment: "22 MIXIN Mixer Input. Requires an external matching network" quote directly from datasheet in pinout table description. @Andyaka

Comment: You said LNAOUT first and I couldn't see the note you explicitly wrote.

Comment: See solution p9

Comment: A quick check with a Smith chart shows that the series LC network before MIXIN doesn't provide 50 Ohm matching to the bandpass filter.

Comment: Yes, but only if we consider this two LC components - we don't know compoments inside mixer. I asked if it is a part of 50 Ohm matching impedance accroding to datasheet.

Comment: My understanding would be that the impedance seen looking into the MIXIN port is completely described by its S11 parameter. In fact, the table where this parameter appears is labeled "MAX2335 Mixer Input Impedance in HGHL Mode".

Answer (score 0):

Note on page 5 of the datasheet for MIXIN and LNAOUT pins, the components are required for the matching network.  They also serve other purposes.  The series capacitors serve as DC blocks as mentioned in the datasheet.  The inductor and resistors connected to LNAOUT also serve as a bias feed to the LNA.